# How to avoid kernel shutdown when importing a file

Tags: kernel, kernel-startup

I am importing a CIF file and the Kernel shutdown (Mathematica 10). The only instruction is this

Import["myfilename.cif"]

I tried CheckAbort unsuccessfully.
How can I catch the error and keep running?

The input file can be downloaded from [COD 1504113.cif](http://nanocrystallography.research.pdx.edu/static/mcodcif/1/50/41/1504113.cif)

Comment: The kernel crash is a bug, most likely in string pattern matching. Which version are you using and would it be possible to provide the input file?

Comment: @ilian I edited the question with version and input file

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The kernel crash is a bug which arises from deep recursion in string pattern matching. It has been fixed in version 10.1.0 and later, by updating to a more modern version of the [PCRE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perl_Compatible_Regular_Expressions) library and switching to a non-recursive approach in certain cases.

I am not aware of a workaround applicable to older versions, but it doesn't crash with 10.1 and 10.2:

```
Import["http://nanocrystallography.research.pdx.edu/static/mcodcif/1/50/41/1504113.cif"] 
// Short

(* {"_656" -> ".", "_656" -> ".", <<154>>, "_symmetry_space_group_name_H-M" -> "P -1"} *)
```

Comment: I just upgraded to version 10.2 and problem solved!